# How to pass function/array into ODEINT?

Tags: python, odeint

I have a second-order ODE:

`a*x''(t) + b*u''(t) = 0`,

where `a = 5`, `b = 10` and `u''(t)` is a function:

```
def d2u_dt2(t):
    if t < 5:
        30*np.sin(t*np.pi/5)
    else:
        -20*np.sin(np.pi*(t-5)/6)
```

My code on how I'm tring to solve it:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 11, 50)
udot = interp1d(t, [d2u_dt2(t) for t in t])

def dSdx(x, S, udot):
    x, v = S
    return [v,
           -b/a * udot]
v_0 = 0
x_0 = 0
S_0 = (x_0, v_0)
b = 10
a = 5
sol = odeint(dSdx, y0=S_0, t=t, tfirst=True, args=(udot(t)))
xscal = sol.T[0]
xdot = sol.T[1]
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an
inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous
part.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because you are passing an array `udot(t)` and setting this array as an element in the function `dSdx`, which is not allowed.

To tackle this, you can create a function for `udot` and evaluate it for each iteration inside `dSdx` as follows:

```python
def fun_udot(x):
    return udot(x)

def dSdx(x, S):
    x, v = S
    return [v, -b/a * fun_udot(x)]
```

In the code above, I have created a function `fun_udot` which takes `x` and returns the interpolation result just for this `x` value. And this function is called inside `dSdx` every time when `odeint` solves the ODE. This way, you get `udot` at every `x` for which the ODE is being solved. This can be solved as follows:

```python
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np

def d2u_dt2(t):
    if t < 5:
        30*np.sin(t*np.pi/5)
    else:
        -20*np.sin(np.pi*(t-5)/6)

t = np.linspace(0, 11, 50)
udot = interp1d(t, [d2u_dt2(t) for t in t])

v_0 = 0
x_0 = 0
b = 10
a = 5
S_0 = (x_0, v_0)
sol = odeint(dSdx, y0=S_0, t=t, tfirst=True)
xscal = sol.T[0]
xdot = sol.T[1]
```